# Time out to Website using xpage in HCL Notes

Tags: iframe, xpages, lotus-notes, hcl-notes

I want to build a widget that can show me Departure monitor for buses and trains embedded in the note client
Im using HCL Notes 12.0.2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <iframe
        src="https://www.wikipedia.de/"
        style="width: 600px; height: 500px;">
    </iframe>
    <embed
        src="https://www.wikipedia.de/"
        width="600" height="500">
    </embed>
    </xp:view>
```

When i open the Database its a xpage in firefox i shows everything.
But when i open the Database in the NotesClient i shows nothing and than the error "time out to Website".
Is it because there is no support anymore for embedded browsers in Notes?

Comment: Hi Lucas, FYI coincidently I was attempting the same thing last week and abandoned it for the same reasons and the same assumption or more that XPiNC was never really finished off. Don't know if I am right though.

Comment: Hi!
I just gave it a quick test and it worked for me ;)
Best bet is, that you have an (authenticating) proxy between the Notes Client and the Internet and Notes/XPiNC does not use that. 
Try enabling Proxy Settings in location document of the Notes Client.